# How can I do a call in ios?

Tags: ios, ios5

I need to do a call in background to a number and, if is possible, to enter a code during the call. Can I do this?

This call must be done via user's phone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in background? No. You can always use

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1234567890"]];
```

to make a call, but it will open the Phone app